How many doors are closed if initially they were in open-state.
If $D_1,D_2,D_3,...,D_{900}$ are $900$ doors and $P_1,P_2,P_3,...,P_{300}$ are $300$ persons. Initially all doors are open. Changing the status of all doors means closing the door if it is open and opening the door if it is closed.$P_1$ changes the status of all doors. Then $P_2$ changes the status of the doors $D_2,D_4,...,D_{900}$(i.e. the doors having numbers which are multiples of $2$), then $P_3$ changes the status of doors $D_3,D_6,D_9,...,D_{900}$ (i.e. doors which have numbers which are multiples of $3$) and this process is continued till $P_{300}$ changes the status of door $D_{900}$.
Then find the number of doors which are finally closed after this process.
My Attempt
After much thinking I find that a door will be remain in open state if it has been operated upon even number of times and will be in closed state if it has been operated upon odd number of times.
Also a door will be operated upon as many number of times as the number of divisors of the number written on it. So for door to be in closed state the number on the door must have been a perfect square as it is only perfect square which has odd number of divisors.
So, such doors would be $D_1,D_4,D_9,...,D_{784},D_{841},D_{900}$ i.e $30$ doors will be in closed state.
Is my answer correct. Can there be a mathematical way to do it

Note the nuance here that there are not the same number of doors as people.  Note for example that there was not a person # $450$, nor will there be a person # $324$ and so on.  Does this affect things?  (Yes).  How?

@CalvinLin To be fair, the OP already seems to have arrived at that conclusion and/or has already seen the more traditional version of this problem where there are as many people as there are doors and has seen the connection to perfect squares, so I don't find your hint necessary.  The real challenge here is how the problem changes by having fewer than the full amount of people going through affecting the doors, which drastically alters the final answer.

@JMoravitz Ah, I didn't notice the nuance about person 300. $\quad$ The idea of the hint of pairing things up still does. EG For door > 451, we want all non-squares. For door 301-450, if even we want ..., if odd we want ....

I think we need to focus on doors numbered 301 to 600 and then from 601 to 900. For door numbered 301 to 600 they will have one divisor less. For door numbered 601 to 900, odd numbered doors will have one divisor less whereas even numbered divisor will have two less divisors. I don't know whether I am thinking correctly

As you have observed we just have to count how many of the doors were operated odd number of times. We can pretty easily see that, this number of operations performed on $D_n$ will be equal to number of divisors of $n$, that are greater than or equal to $300$ (since there are only $300$ people). Let's divide the problem into $3$ cases.
Case $1$: $n \in \{1, 2, \dots,300\}$
Since every divisor of a numbers is not greater than that number. So by your observation we have to count only those numbers, that are the perfect squares (since only them will have odd number of divisors). And there are $\fbox{17}$ of them.
Case $2$: $n \in \{301, 302, \dots,600\}$
Let's notice that divisors come in pairs $\left\{d, \frac{n}{d}\right\}$. Now observe that, since $n \leqslant 600$:
$$
d \geqslant2 \implies \frac{n}{d} \leqslant 300
$$
So the only divisor that is ommited is the number itself. Therefore we have to count, how many numbers in the set $\{301, 302, \dots, 600\}$ have EVEN number of divisors. Since there are $7$ perfect squares in that set, thus there are $\fbox{293}$ such numbers.
Case $3$: $n \in \{601, 602, \dots,900\}$
Similarly, since $n \leqslant 900$:
$$
d \geqslant 3 \implies \frac{n}{d} \leqslant 300
$$
So we also ommit the number itself. However we have to now consider what happens to even numbers, since if $2|n$ we have $\frac{n}{2} > 300 $ (because $n > 600$), so we ommit one more divisor. So generally we have to count in: perfect squares that are even AND non-perfect squares that are odd.
There are $6$ in total perfect squares in our set (beginning with $25^2$, ending on $30^2$), so half of them is even, thus we have $\fbox{3}$ such numbers. Moreover there are $150$ odd numbers in the set, from which $3$ are perfect squares, so there are $\fbox{147}$ numbers that we want to count.
After all the answer is:
$$
17 + 293 + 3 + 147 = 460
$$
$\textit{Edit:}$
Please note, that for pair $\left\{d, \frac{n}{d}\right\}$ we can say WLOG $d \leqslant \frac{n}{d}$ and thus $d \leqslant \sqrt{n}$. In our case $\sqrt{n} \leqslant 30 < 300$, so we can indeed say that both $d$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ are divisors less than or equal to $300$.

The answer is correct. Thanks
